# Problemas ao passar objeto instanciado por parametro da função com php

Tags: php

Tenho um arquivo **php** que instancia uma classe, porém não estou conseguindo passar este objeto instanciado como parâmetro para outra classe.

Exemplo:

```
$usuario = new Usuario();
$email = new Email();
$email->send($usuario);
```

Na classe **Email** não consigo usar os getters and setters da classe **usuario**.

```
class Email {
    function send($usuario) {
        mail($usuario->getId());
    }
}
```

Comment: Coloca o código de `Email::send` também

Comment: Pronto, coloquei.

Comment: Mas a função não tem nome? `function($usuario) {`

Comment: Opa, esqueci de botar, chama-se: send.

Comment: `mail()`  é aquela função padrão do php? `$usuario->getId()` retorna algum erro?

Comment: Bem, na vdd isso aí é só um exemplo. Meu código é bem mais complexo que isso. Mas mesmo que eu colocar `return $usuario->getId()` ele não funciona

Comment: @Krint então edite a pergunta e corrija. Coloque pelo menos este método por completo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema que você está tendo é de [Injeção de Dependência](https://www.treinaweb.com.br/blog/entendendo-injecao-de-dependencia/) .

A dependência de uma classe se dá quando se "injeta", passa uma classe para ser trabalhada dentro da outra.

> Isso quer dizer que, para que haja uma injeção de dependência, a instanciação de um objeto não deve se dar dentro da classe, mas do lado de fora dela e então, injetada.

Uma das formas de realizar isso é injetando a classe externa através do **método construtor**.

Vamos ao exemplo:

```
<?php

class Email  
{
    public function send()
    {
        // TODO
    }
}

class Usuario  
{
    protected $email;

    //Injeção de dependência através do método construtor
    public function __construct(Email $email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;
    }

    public function porEmail()
    {
        $this->email->send();
    }
}
```

> __construct() é como se declara um método construtor em PHP, diferente de linguagens como Java onde se utiliza o mesmo nome da classe, por exemplo: public Usuario().

Repare que agora ao chamar o método `$command->porEmail()` estamos na verdade acionando o método `send()` da classe `$email` , por exemplo, podemos fazer assim:

```
$email = new email();

$anunciar = new Usuario($email);
$anunciar->porEmail();
```

Note que a classe `Usuario` recebe por injeção de dependência `$email`. Todo esse processo que fizemos significa injeção de dependência. Viu como é simples?

Comment: Sua explicação de injeção de dependência é boa, mas será que é esse mesmo o problema dele? Não tenho certeza pelo que ele disse até agora.

Comment: Alterei o exemplo para ficar mais claro e adequar ao problema dele. Acredito que seja isso que ele queira fazer.

Comment: Mas isso ele aparentemente já está fazendo, apenas não está especificando o tipo do parâmetro no construtor. Porém, se tirar isso, funciona perfeitamente (http://ideone.com/bOgTHR). É por isso que estamos falando que provavelmente este não é o problema.

Comment: Na verdade era bem este o problema. Quando eu usei desta forma que o @DNick diz, funcionou perfeitamente

Answer (score 1):

na classe email no seu metodo send antes do parametro especifica o obj q vai passar tipo

```
public function send(Usuario $usuario){
// seu codigo
}
```

Espero que isso seja o que vc procura

Comment: Eu preciso declarar o objeto Usuario?

Comment: Não é necessário. Isso apenas limita o tipo de parâmetro que o método aceita, pois para qualquer objeto de outro tipo um erro `TypeError` seria lançado. Mas se você não especificar, não tem problema. Provavelmente esta não é a solução.