# Posso colocar namespace em classes antigas?

Tags: php, namespace

Bom pessoal, trabalho em uma empresa que tem um sistema enorme, e usamos o Doctrine para fazer o Mapeamento de nossas tabelas, porém isso já é muito antigo usamos o Doctrine a muito tempo e na época não tinhamos conhecimento de namespaces.

Hoje em dia se eu colocar apenas o namespace em todas as classes DAO para usar no sistema inteiro com ajuda do autoload PSR4 do composer daria algum erro  no sistema, ou funcionaria normal ?

Comment: Nao tem problema nenhum, voce pode colocar eles mesmo depois, eles existem justamente para evitar conflitos entre variaveis com o mesmo nome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como já deve saber e como já descrito no comentário desta pergunta os *namespaces* tem por finalidade evitar conflitos de nomes. Tais conflitos podem ocorrer em relação aos nomes das:

1. Classes;
2. Funções;
3. Variáveis; e
4. Constantes.

Como mencionou seu projeto *legacy* no momento não utiliza *namespaces* e funciona perfeitamente. Isso quer dizer que não há os conflitos de nomes nos casos citados acima.

Antes de realizar esta alteração só há uma obrigatoriedade. A versão do seu PHP deve ser `>= 5.3.0`.

Se isto estiver ok, não haverá nenhuma objeção. Esta alteração só beneficiará a manutenção do sistema como um todo. Ótima decisão.

Comment: Quero implementar injeção de dependência por isso preciso muito de colocar os namespaces nas classes.

Comment: @LucasLima sem problemas. Os namespaces serão de grande ajuda. Acredito que já tenha o conhecimento de como aplicar a injeção de dependência, mas como conhecimento nunca é demais, recentemente postei [uma resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/222266/problemas-ao-passar-objeto-instanciado-por-parametro-da-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-com-php/222296#222296) sobre injeção de dependência

Comment: Uma mudança dessas, ainda mais mexendo em sistema legado, certeza que problemas apareceram, mas nada que não possa ser tratado. O que você quer fazer é possível e viável.

Comment: Sim ja tenho o conhecimento sobre injeção de dependência e eu vou dar uma lida no seu post, toda informação é bem-vinda, o sistema tem mais de 10 anos, espero que dê tudo certo !